# Cell auto adjust height when pulling data from other cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've built a spreadsheet with a summary report that auto formats fine, except in situations where the text in **one cell** and is **too long to fit into a cell**.

The report pulls info from cells under another tab in Excel. The cells are all set to text-wrap, and they do this, but **the rows do not automatically get taller to accommodate the text wrap**.

I'm using this simple equation to pull data from a cell in another tab where 2B is the name of the tab, and A11 is the cell:

```
='2B'!A11
```

**Is there a way to set a row to automatically get taller when the info being imported into the cell needs to wrap?**